# Jquery animate easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Quick question : how do I call jQuery's `animate()` without any easing parameters? e.g. without any effects.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write

```
$('#elem').animate({
    top: '0px',
    left: '0px'
}, 5000, 'linear');
```

Extract from [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called `swing`, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   `linear`.

Comment: i think 'linear' is an easing parameter

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti, exactly! Constant pace literally means no easing.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the easing parameters.

Comment: If you leave it out, the default will be used, which is 'swing'.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the documentation:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

you just don't write the easing parameter